# How to remove WebBrowser flicker?

Tags: c#, html, background, browser, flicker

I'm using WebBrowser Control for my chat application. Every time it adds user's message - it refreshes WebBrowser with its new content. And it works good.
But after I added a background in html code it started to flicker every time it refreshes.
Here's my Navigate() method:

```
public void Navigate(string url)
{
    string text = File.ReadAllText(url);
    if (bg.Length > 0)
        webBrowser1.DocumentText = text.Replace("%bg%", "background=\"" + bg + "\"");
    else
        webBrowser1.DocumentText = text;
}
```

and this is my html file header:

```
addText("<html>\r\n<head>\r\n<meta charset=utf-8>\r\n</head>\r\n<body %bg% bgproperties=\"fixed\" onload=\"window.scrollTo(0,2147483647);\">\r\n<span style=\"line-height: 20px\" style=\"font-family: Arial; font-size: 14px\">\r\n<font color=black>", NewLine.No);
```

Every time user adds a message, my program adds it to the end of html file and executes Navigate() method.

Have you got any ideas to remove flicker?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of reloading a new document every time, set the `InnerHTML` of the existing `Document.Body`.

Comment: If you mean "webBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerHtml = text;" instead of "webBrowser1.DocumentText = text;" - it doesn't change anything. Background image still flashing when loading.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following 2 lines in your `<Head>` tag

```
<meta http-equiv="Page-Enter" content="blendTrans(Duration=0)">
<meta http-equiv="Page-Exit" content="blendTrans(Duration=0)">
```

it is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I added:

```
<meta http-equiv='Page-Exit' content='filter: expression(document.execCommand("BackgroundImageCache", false, true))'>
```

to my html code and it's not flashing. I don't know how it works (I don't know html), just spent some time googling for the solution.

And it's strange, because I can replace:
`expression(document.execCommand("BackgroundImageCache", false, true))` 
to anything else and it still works.